# Prove vector is orthogonal to columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say $\vec{e} = \vec{b} - A\vec{x}$, where $\vec{x} = (A^\intercal A)^{-1} A^\intercal \vec{b}$ and $A$ is a non-square matrix. Show that $\vec{e}$ is orthogonal to the columns of $A$ (AKA $A^\intercal \vec{e} = 0$).

I tried saying that $(A^\intercal A)^{-1} = A^{-1}(A^\intercal)^{-1}$ and $AA^{-1} = I$, but the problem is that $A$ is non-square, meaning it doesn't have an inverse. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I would suggest that you write out what $A^Te$ is and look at $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a direct computation; you only deal with the inverse of the square matrix  $A^tA $: $$A^te=A^tb-A^tA (A^tA )^{-1}A^tb=A^tb-A^tb=0. $$